# How to set the timezone to EST throughout the rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I want to use EST throughout the app. I have set the

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

what I want is, I have to get all the time I have used like `"DateTime.now"` and it now returns time in my local timezone but I want it to return date time in EST. Also I have date time range picker and I get the start date and end date and parse the string to time using

```
(params[:start_date]).to_time
```

which also returns the date time in local zone and instead i want all those to return in EST. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in database date-time would be saved in UTC format unless you have selected a specific TimeZone for Active Record and it would be easier if you have to meddle with multiple TimeZones. But, while you access the values you will get the values in you selected TimeZone.

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)
```

Now, suppose you have a datetime value in UTC from table as

`datetime1 = "2014-08-25 10:25:57 +0000"`

You can convert it to the selected timezone `'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` as below,

```
Time.zone.parse(datetime1) => Mon, 25 Aug 2014 06:25:57 EDT -04:00
```

Then, if you need it in a proper format, use method `strftime`.

```
Time.zone.parse("2014-08-25 10:25:57 +0000").strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") => "25-08-2014 06:25:57"
```

Hoep it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.now` and `Time.now` doesn't respect `Time.zone` and will always use the server time.  If the machine you're using is set to a different timezone, these 2 will use that timezone.

`to_time` on the other hand defaults to local timezone as mentioned in [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_time) (although just tried this out and I get utc by default).  To get these times in the timezone set, append `in_time_zone`

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone
Time.now.in_time_zone
string.to_time.in_time_zone
```

There are some shortcuts for these though.  The following code will return the timestamps in the current timezone

```
Time.zone.now
Time.zone.parse(string)
```